# Properties of the space of $ T $-invariant probability measures over a compact topological space.

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T: X \to X$ be a continuos map defined on the compact space (Maybe Haussdorff) $X$. 
Denote by $M_T$ the space of $T$-invariant probability measures defined over the Sigma Algebra of Borel sets. Prove the following:

- Show that $M_T$ is non-empty
- Show that $M_T$ is compact and Haussdorff.

**Important remark:**

- I know the result is true for spaces which are Compact and Metric.
- I think that the result **is false for general Compact and Haussdorff Topological Spaces**. If the result is false, please give me a counterexample. I tried to find a counterexample but I couldn't.

At the moment I'm more interested to discover if $M_T$ is nonempty rather than the second proposition.

Comment: My browser fails at displaying the unicode code-point after $T$. Can you fix this by using MathJax?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean D:

Comment: This symbol:  displays incorrectly in my browser. What is supposed to be between $T$ and _-invariant_?

Comment: I erased it (from the context I think it wasn't meant to be there ?)

Comment: I don't understand your last remark. Isn't the identity function a continuous transformation from $X$ to $X$?

Comment: @ZilinJ. The identity has a T invariant probability measure. Namely $\mu(X)=1$ otherwise $\mu(O)=0$.

Comment: @Ergos I am still confused. Can you please clarify your remarks? It seems contradicting that in the question you asked for a proof for compact (maybe Hausdorff) space $X$ and in the remark, you said it is false for compact Hausdorff space. Also your last remark, what kind of examples are you trying to find? Are you looking for a continuous transformation that does not have a invariant probability measure?

Comment: @ZilinJ. I think that the result is false but I don't know if is false or not, is just a thought, that's why I'm open to both possibilites (a proof that is correct, incorrect or a possible counterexample)

Comment: I think this is true. Since $X$ is compact Hausdorff, we know that $C(X)$, the space of continuous functions on $X$ is a normed linear space. And the set of regular Borel probability measures is a subset of the unit sphere of the dual of $C(X)$, it is compact and Hausdorff in the weak* topology. And I think as the same way of the proof in compact metric spaces, I think this is also true in the case of compact Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $M_T$ is compact Hausdorff (in weak * topology) has been pointed out in the comment. The proof is similar to the case in compact metric spaces. I learned this from [Clinton Conley](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~clintonc/).

> Fact 1: If $T: X\to X$ is continuous, then $T_*: M_T \to M_T$ is weak * continuous.

Proof: By definition of weak * convergence, $\mu_n \to \mu $ iff $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu \forall f\in C(X)$, in particular $\int f\circ T d\mu_n \to \int f \circ T d\mu \ \ \ \forall f\in C(X)$ so $\int f dT_*\mu_n \to \int f  dT_*\mu \ \ \ \forall f\in C(X)$.

> Fact 2: There exists $\mu\in M_T$ such that $T_*\mu=\mu$.

Consider an abelian group (notice the actions commute) generated by $K=\{\frac{1}{n} (1+ T_* + \cdots + T_*^{n-1}): n\in \mathbb{N} \}$. Since $M_T$ is compact Hausdorff, and also for any finite $s_i\in K, (s_1 \circ \cdots s_k)[M_T]\subset \bigcap_i s_i[M_T]$ so by finite intersection property. In particular there exists $\mu\in \bigcap_{s\in K} s[M_T]$.

Now it's left to show that $\mu$ is invariant. Suppose not, there exists continuous function $f\in C(X,[0,1])$ such that $\int f\circ T d\mu \neq \int f d\mu$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be smaller that the absolute value of their difference. Pick $n$ large such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and also $\nu\in M_T$ with $\mu=\frac{1}{n} (\nu+\cdots+ T_*^{n-1}\nu)$. Then $T_*\mu-\mu=\frac{1}{n} (T_*^n \nu- \nu)$. Then $\epsilon\leq |\int f\circ T d\mu - \int f d\mu|=|\frac{1}{n}\int fd(T_*\nu-\nu)|\leq \frac{1}{n}$, contradiction.

Comment: That looks like it works, but a couple of comments. I think you are using $M_T$ to denote the set of Borel probability measures on $X$, whereas the question is using it to denote the invariant probability measures. Also, to identify the probability measures with the dual of $C(X)$, you should really be restricting to the regular measures.

Comment: Indeed. The $M_T$ here is the space of Borel probability measures.